# How do you run the alexa snap?

Tags: snap, ubuntu-mate

I installed the alexa snap.

How do I run it?

```
snap list
Name                                  Version          Rev    Tracking         Publisher      Notes
alexa                                 1.1              2      latest/beta      data-art       -
```